# Proxy access from JBoss

Tags: jboss, proxy

We have an app running on JBoss. In many installations the server is running behind a firewall that denies it access to the internet except through a proxy.
Now my task is to find out how to use this proxy when authentication is necessary.

Configuring JBoss to use a proxy is no problem with `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy_host -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxy_port`, but I see no way to indicate the username and password.

On a non-EJB-app I have had success using `Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("test", "test"))` where ProxyAuthenticator is extending Authenticator. This, however, does not work on JBoss.

A sub-problem I have to this case is that the server and the non-EJB-app needs to have access to local resources without using the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got this this to work. With the two links in Richs post and some trial and error it now works as requiered.
At the moment I have only implemented basic authentication and I will have to add other authentication types in the future.

A big obstruction was that I started configuring the JVM with `-Dhttp.proxyHost and -Dhttp.proxyPort`. That somehow confused the JVM more than it helped. With that configuration the `ProxyAuthenticator.getPasswordAuthentication()` was never called. So it is necessary also to set a default ProxySelector.

The code leads everything through the proxy - also calls to local addresses. Soon I'll need to work on a solution to this :-) (Any ideas?)

This is what I do to set it up:

```
ProxySelector proxySelector;
if (proxySelector == null) {
    proxySelector = new MyProxySelector(ProxySelector.getDefault(), address, port);
}

ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);
Authenticator.setDefault(ProxyAuthenticator.getInstance());
```

MyProxySelector:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MyProxySelector extends ProxySelector {
    /**
     * Keep a reference on the default ProxySelector
     */
    private ProxySelector defaultProxySelector = null;
    private static ProxySelector proxySelector;

    /*
     * Inner class representing a Proxy and a few extra data
     */
    private class InnerProxy {
        Proxy proxy;
        SocketAddress addr;
         // How many times did we fail to reach this proxy?
        int failedCount = 0;

        InnerProxy(InetSocketAddress a) {
            addr = a;
            proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, a);
        }

        SocketAddress address() {
            return addr;
        }

        Proxy toProxy() {
            return proxy;
        }

        int failed() {
            return ++failedCount;
        }
    }

    /* A list of proxies, indexed by their address. */
    private HashMap<SocketAddress, InnerProxy> proxies = new HashMap<SocketAddress, InnerProxy>();

    public MyProxySelector(ProxySelector def, String address, Integer port) {
        // Save the previous default
        defaultProxySelector = def;

        // Populate the HashMap (List of proxies)
        InnerProxy i;
        if (address != null && port != null) {
            i = new InnerProxy(new InetSocketAddress(address, port));
            proxies.put(i.address(), i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the method that the handlers will call.
     *
     * @param uri
     * @return a List of proxies.
     */
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI can't be null.");
        }

        // If it's a http (or https) URL, then we use our own
        // list.
        String protocol = uri.getScheme();
        if ("http".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol) || "https".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol)) {
            List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
            for (InnerProxy p : proxies.values()) {
                proxyList.add(p.toProxy());
            }

            if (proxyList.size() == 0) {
                proxyList.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
            }
            return proxyList;
        }

         // Not HTTP or HTTPS (could be SOCKS or FTP)
         // defer to the default selector.
        if (defaultProxySelector != null) {
            return defaultProxySelector.select(uri);
        } else {
            List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
            proxyList.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
            return proxyList;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method called by the handlers when it failed to connect
     * to one of the proxies returned by select().
     *
     * @param uri
     * @param sa
     * @param ioe
     */
    public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
        // Let's stick to the specs again.
        if (uri == null || sa == null || ioe == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments can't be null.");
        }

        // Let's lookup for the proxy
        InnerProxy p = proxies.get(sa);
        if (p != null) {
            // It's one of ours, if it failed more than 3 times
            // let's remove it from the list.
            if (p.failed() >= 3)
                proxies.remove(sa);
        } else {
            // Not one of ours, let's delegate to the default.
            if (defaultProxySelector != null)
                defaultProxySelector.connectFailed(uri, sa, ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

ProxyAuthenticator:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.RuntimeCryptoException;

import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class ProxyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private static ProxyAuthenticator authenticator;

    public ProxyAuthenticator(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
    }

    public static Authenticator getInstance(String user, String password) {
        if (authenticator == null) {
            authenticator = new ProxyAuthenticator(user, password);
        }
        return authenticator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the app from using the proxy for certain hosts with the following property:

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.foo.com|localhost"
```

As for authenticating against a proxy, you may find [this](http://community.jboss.org/message/564153) and [this](http://community.jboss.org/thread/162475) useful.

Comment: The first link presupposes that you are running JBoss 5.1.0 GA and JBossWS 3.3.1. We are running 4.3.0 GA :-(
The second link only uses Authenticator.setDefault, which I have already tried.

Comment: Are you able to explain in what sense this does not work? The only other solution I can think of is to have an open proxy to the closed proxy and to limit only certain apps from being able to access this other proxy through some kind of network policy...